# How to place only the first subfigure at the centre?

Tags: subplot

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption{Caption} 
\label{fig:1}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{} 
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
\caption{} \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig3}
\caption{} \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig4}
\caption{} \label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig5}
\caption{} \label{fig:f}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
```

which generates the following result for the figure:
[image]

I would like the top figure, i.e. the first one, to lie at the centre of the plot while the remaining figures are left as they are. Like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have only posted a fragment we can not run but as you have a paragraph end after the first but not after the second you would just need `\centering` at the start

Comment: I managed to solve it by simply putting \begin{subfigure} ... \end{subfigure} inside a \begin{center} ... \end{center}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Employing a `center` envrionment in this manner probably ends up inserting some unwarnted (vertical) whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are employing the `subcaption` and `graphicx` packages, I can confirm that @DavidCarlisle's suggestion is correct: Just provide a `\centering` directive sometime before the first `subfigure` environment.

I would also like to suggest that you reduce the widths of the `subfigure` environments to around `0.475\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove demo option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering  % <-- new
\caption{Caption} 
\label{fig:1}

\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{} 
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
\caption{} \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig3}
\caption{} \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig4}
\caption{} \label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig5}
\caption{} \label{fig:f}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```